# will tinycore work with S110 wireless adapter?

Tags: linux, wifi

will tinycore work out of the box with S110 lenovo netbook?

Wireless is obviously the first issue to be encountered? can anybody report that it will work out ofthe box? or i will have to spend some time on it?

Comment: please put output of  `lspci |egrep -i wireless`command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is easier to deal with in three parts:

**1) Does tinycore use a normal linux kernel?**

According to [this page](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki%3acustom_kernel), yes (*"In general the standard TC kernel is a fairly standard Linux kernel, meaning that is has just a few set of patches applied."*), and it seems you can build a kernel from the vanilla sources for use on tinycore.

Hardware drivers are part of the kernel, and linux distros don't write their own kernels (that's why they are called linux).  They all use more or less the same one.  Hence, this question is important because now, rather than having to find someone who's used tinycore on the device, you just need to find someone who's used *linux* on the device -- that is, any linux distro that uses a "fairly standard kernel", as tinycore does.

**2) What is the wifi hardware on the lenovo S110?**

This question is important because the wifi device is almost certainly not unique to the lenovo, so if you can find out what that hardware is, then you just need to find out if there is support for that specific chipset in the linux kernel.  [This page with S110 specs](http://support.lenovo.com/en_US/downloads/detail.page?DocID=PD023081) seems to list quite a few different things under "WLAN/WiMax card" and "WLAN/bluetooth combo" -- I don't know if this means it has both these things or if there are two models.  Anyway, googling a couple of those reveals they are, in fact, 802.11 wifi chipsets:

- Atheros AR5B95
- Realtek 8188CE

I'm going to stop here for two reasons.  The first is that since there's so many different chipsets listed for the one netbook wifi, you will need to do some more research to find out exactly which one applies.  The second is that the 8188CE is pretty common, and that's what's in the toshiba satellite I'm hammering away on right now.  There is indeed an in-tree linux driver for it which works out of the box, no hassles.  So if this is the chip, you are good to go.

I've assumed up to this point that you don't actually have a S110 yet.  If you do parts 2 and 3 here are much easier to deal with.  If you have an S110 *and* you have some flavour of linux on it already, then question 1 is enough: WRT hardware support, tinycore will be exactly the same as whatever distro you have right now.

**3) Is there an in-tree linux driver for *_*___?**

That is a specific question with a yes or no answer.  You can't really ask it in general WRT the lenovo S110, but you can ask it WRT a specific item that makes up the netbook.  Questions like this are easy to answer, and so they get answered quickly and easily ;)

One place to check yourself is to download a kernel source and browser through `make menuconfig`.  You don't have to build a kernel or go through everything; just check to see if there is an option somewhere than seems applicable under `Device Drivers -> Network Suppport -> Wireless LAN` (for the Realtek, it is `Realtek 8192CE/8188CE`).  A stock distro kernel (such as the "fairly standard" one apparently used by tinycore) will include most of these as modules.  On the off chance it doesn't, you can always roll your own.

*In-tree* just means the driver is included as part of the normal linux kernel source, which makes a big difference in terms of quality and ease of use.

So that's not a perfect "Yes FateZero I am running tinycore on the lenovo S110 now and it's all good" answer.  If you wait long enough, that person may show up.  In the meantime, hopefully you have a better understanding of what your question entails and that will help you to deal with other similar questions in the future.

Comment: you are awesome :)) @goldilocks 

i tried it out on S110 and wifi works perfectly, as well as on 3 other laptops and all works fine :D


the only issue i have now is that on S110, tinycore extensions doesn't support vga driver out of the box! i coudnt even use vim, it is very messy!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: also worth noting that I dont think i need APT on tinycore... :) 

i like the repository it got! irssi, vim, firefox in a couple of mins! and you can even make your own image out of tinycore, so what else can you ask for!!

i want to encrypt my home directory, use tinycore on low cheap single device for a database service like Redis or anything similar, to see how would that compare to an alternative expensive solution!!